# How to push the data from rds to kafka queue in json format

Tags: mysql, json, apache-kafka

I use kafka topic to receive message from mysql database.I need to write python code to push the data in json format from mysql to kafka topic.My requirement is to get the output in json format but not in raw strings.

Below is the python code to dump the mysql table data to kafka topic in json format.

**Code:**

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='xyz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', database='testdb',user='stdnt', password='pssw123')

cursor=connection.cursor()

statement='SELECT * FROM patients_vital_info'

cursor.execute(statement)
data=cursor.fetchall()

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                                api_version=(0,11,5),value_serializer=lambda x:
                                                        json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))
for i in data:
    producer.send('test',i)
    sleep(1)
```

**Output from kafka topic in raw string format:**

```
[3, 69, 175]
[4, 68, 171]
[5, 72, 177]
[1, 78, 162]
[2, 66, 157]
[3, 72, 156]
```

The output should be pushed in json format while writing the message to kafka queue.

**Expected output:**

```
{"bp":140,"heartBeat":73,"Customerid":1}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.fetchall()` returns a row iterator, not a dictionary with key-value pairs of column to value. Your data is also, correctly, a JSON array

You'd need to build the JSON yourself if you want to include column names or use Kafka Connect JDBC source / Debezium rather than Python to do exactly what you're looking for